# What do you call the relation between two functions that behave the same

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let's say I have two functions, `f(x)` and `g(x)` where for every `x` we know that if `f'(x) < 0`, then `g'(x) < 0` and the other way round.

In other words, `f'(x) * g'(x) > 0` for every `x`.
No other information is given (like who is larger or anything like that).

Does this relation have a specific name?

Thanks

Comment: Does 'the other way around' include $f'(x_0)=0$ iff $g'(x_0)=0$?

Comment: @Semiclassical - Yes.

Comment: I don't know a specific name for it, but this would mean that the functions are increasing and decreasing on the same intervals and that they attain their extreme values (if any) at the same $x$-values. I'm guessing this is not new and you are in fact looking for a specific term for this...

Comment: @StackTD - precisely.